# batch file to install application (Adobe Reader)

Tags: scripting, batch

I previously used ninite to install this. However, this is no longer supported through ninite anymore. I usually install this manually but I know where a way to automate this using a batch script of some kind. Here's what I have:

```
msiexec.exe /I AcroRead.msi /QN
```

From what I've read, this should work, but unfortunate it's not installing. I've also tried this:

```
start /d "\\directoryToMyFile\" AcroRead.msi
```

It runs the file, but there a prompt in which it needs me to select the "Install" button.

Am I taking the best approach? I have a batch file that installs several other programs just fine, but for Adobe Reader it's giving me so much trouble.

Answer (score 1):

Adobe Reader is a bit more complicated to automate it's installation, since it requires you to first generate transform file in which you configure installation parameters.

Transform file can be generated using proper version of software called "Adobe Customization Wizard" (version of Wizard must be the same as the version of Reader you will be installing) and which is available for download from Adobes site. Once you have that software installed, than you basically follow this steps:

1. Launch Adobe Customization Wizard and load Adobe Reader msi file into it (File -> Load Package)
2. Go through the wizard pages and customise it according to your own
   needs
3. Once you're done customising paramteres, save mst file in same
   folder as msi (Transform -> Generate Transform...)
4. Silently install Adobe reader using cmd line:
   `msiexec /i AcroPro.msi TRANSFORMS="AcroPro.mst" /qb`

For more command line switches see: http://www.adobe.com/devnet-docs/acrobatetk/tools/AdminGuide/cmdline.html#msi-switches

For basic info about installing and using Wizard tool see that page: https://www.adobe.com/devnet-docs/acrobatetk/tools/Wizard/WizardDC/basics.html